# отправка post get запросов как авторизированный пользователь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью python отправить post get запросы с cookies и token  нашёл решения только пока такое

```
requests.post(url, headers = {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : xtoken, 'cookie' : cookie})
```

но так неудобно нужно  раз в час брать cookie и token они обновляются, а нужно чтоб под логином и паролем заходил и отправлял запрос как можно это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать Selenium для автоматического управления браузером.
Вы сможете легко войти на сайт под нужным логином и паролем и выполнить все действия оттуда, либо просто взять нужные данные о сессии/куки и выполнить запрос вручную.

Comment: Пробивал авторизоваться все нормально, но нужно нажимать на определённые места на сайте но там canvas class а Selenium не может на него нажать так как не видит через него а вручную я беру ток я ж писал что нужно это автоматизировать

Comment: @vladimirGrabar, прошу прощения, некорректно выразился. Имел ввиду брать куки из кода, управляющего браузером, используя `driver.get_cookie('foo')` для получения конкретной переменной или `driver.get_cookies()` для всех.

После этого можете передавать эти куки в старый код или искать способы работы с canvas через selenium.